# Why doesn't this attempt at using sys_write do anything?

Tags: linux, assembly, x86-64, system-calls, gnu-assembler

Here it is:

```
.SECTION .data
    msg: .string "AAAA"

.SECTION .text

.globl _start

_start:
    mov $1, %rax
    mov $1, %rdi
    mov msg, %rsi
    mov $4, %rdx
    syscall
```

Not only does this code *not* segfault, it also outputs nothing.
According to what I've read, a program should call sys_exit, or it would segfault, but this does not happen.

Comment: Try `mov $msg, %rsi`. The instruction `mov msg, %rsi` moves the first eight bytes of `msg` to `%rsi` which is not what you want.

Comment: What happens after the `syscall`, then?  Single-step with a debugger like `gdb` to find out.  Or use `strace ./my_prog`.  BTW, it segfaults for me, as expected, after building with `gcc -static -nostdlib foo.s`

Comment: That's on Arch Linux with gcc7.3.0, `ld` from binutils 2.29.1 where this does segfault in a static executable.  How did you build your executable?

Comment: use intel-syntax. you do not have this problem there.

Comment: @sivizius: `mov rsi, msg` is still a load in GAS's `.intel_syntax noprefix` mode, because it's MASM-style, not NASM-style.  You'd need `mov esi, OFFSET msg`, or `lea rsi, [rip + msg]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> mov msg, %rsi
> ```

This instruction will interpret the data at "msg" as 64-bit value and load that value into the register `rsi`. The instruction does NOT load the address of "msg" into register `rsi`. This could be done by (note the `$`):

```
mov $msg, %rsi
```

> According to what I've read, a program should call sys_exit, or it would segfault, but this does not happen.

You have to be aware **why** the segfault happens:

The CPU does not know where the "end" of your program is. The CPU can also not distinguish between instructions and data.

The bytes `0x8A, 0x07` for example may mean `mov (%rdi),%al` or they may represent the number `1930` - the CPU does not know.

When reaching the end of your program the CPU will try to read the bytes **after** your program and interpret them as instruction.

Now three scenarios are possible:

- As RAM is managed in 4096 byte blocks on x86 systems. So depending on the length of your program up to 4095 bytes of "unused" RAM are following your program.

  The CPU will interpret the (random) bytes in the RAM as (assembler) instructions and execute these instructions.

  When reaching the end of the 4096 byte block a segfault is happening.
- The 4095 bytes contain an instruction that causes a segfault (before the end of the block is reached).
- The 4095 bytes represent instructions which cause the program to exit without any exception or an endless loop.

So maybe in your case the 3rd situation is the case.

Comment: @fuz: use `lea message(%rip), %rsi` for 64-bit static addresses.  `mov $msg, %rsi` is never the best choice for anything, whether it's a PIE or non-PIE executable, regardless of whether it picks a 64-bit immediate or 32-bit sign-extended.  (In a non-PIE executable, the most efficient choice is `mov $msg, %esi`, a 5-byte instruction.)  On my system, `mov $msg, %rsi` picks `movq`, not `movabs`, so it won't link in a PIE executable.

Comment: TL:DR: your two good options are `lea msg(%rip), %rsi` (PIC) or `mov $msg, %esi` (non-PIC, static addresses fit in 32 bits)